# Report Page Tooltip not work on column chart

Tags: powerbi, dax, tooltip, measure

I have a column chart that displays the current weeks data, and the 3 previous weeks based on a slicer that is a date filter from a 'Dates' table.

The chart shows Time and Intensity (from the 'All Week Beginning Data' table) for each week, as a total. I'm looking to get a tooltip that shows the Intensity % for each week.

Any suggestions how I can get the report page tooltip working just like the default one?

Thanks

If I use the formula:

MI Mins % WB =
CALCULATE(
DIVIDE(
SUM('All Week Beginning Data'[Intensity]),
SUM('All Week Beginning Data'[Time]),
0
),
ALL('Dates')
)

... in the default Tooltips field, it works fine, however I want it to look better, so I have created a card on a tooltip report page with the same measure - the tooltip works for the current week when hovering on the chart, but not for the other 3 weeks. This will be because the date filter is 'interacting' with the chart.

Comment: Could you share a sample/mock PBIX? Quite a few different levers and it would be guess work.